# How might I get to the SSL URL defined in the properties of an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have SSL enabled and I am trying to write my own `RequireHttpsAttribute` to allow easy testing with IIS Express. When it redirects, it redirects to port 44301, but I don't want to hard code this, I want to read this from the existing configuration.

```
public sealed class RequireHttpsAlternativePortAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);

        //alter the port in the base classes result
        var baseRedirect = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;
        if (baseRedirect == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No redirect was suppied from the base class");
        }

        var builder = new UriBuilder(baseRedirect.Url);
        var targetPort = 44301; //need this from settings
        if (builder.Port == targetPort) return; //already correct port

        //change the port
        builder.Port = targetPort;
        var redirectResult = new RedirectResult(builder.ToString());
        filterContext.Result = redirectResult;
    }
}
```

44301 is defined in the MVC project properties under SSL URL. My question is, is this accessible during runtime anywhere?